# css repeat background vertically

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to figure out how to vertically repeat a background image on a `<div>`
here's my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/pedenski/Sw6wB/

what im trying to accomplish here is to put a shadow effect on the side of the page. similar with the http://www.adobe.com/ website. you'd see a shadow border on both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have no height for your left and right divs.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Sw6wB/9/) updated JS fiddle.

I've added     `height:100px;` just to show that it works

```
div#right {
    background-image:url(http://i45.tinypic.com/ejv8uq.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:right;
}
```

and here is a fix for left block(`background-position:top right;` and height):

```
div#left {
    background-image:url(http://i47.tinypic.com/2hsc187.png);
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position:top right;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but what i wanted to happen is to let the side borders adjust based on the content in the middle. i want it to stretch or repeat vertically. putting a height:100px only limits me to that fixed height.

Comment: hi, i know this has been answered few days ago, would you be so kind to explain why ` background-position:top right;` should be included?

Comment: Try to remove it ;) In case of jsfiddle - image is longer than available width. Usually background image is attached to top left corner and shadow is not seen without top right position

Answer (score 1):

Write it as -

```
div#left {
    background:url(http://i47.tinypic.com/2hsc187.png) repeat-y left top;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Sw6wB/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `background:url(http://i47.tinypic.com/2hsc187.png) right top repeat-y;`

here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/Sw6wB/13/

Answer (score 1):

Depending on this tag, the image might repeat in horizontal or vertical or both directions.

It takes any of the following values:

- `repeat` : This value tells the image to be repeated in both directions
- `repeat-x` : This value tells the image to be repeated in vertical direction only
- `repeat-y` : This value tells the image to be repeated in horizontal directions
- `no-repeat` : This value tells that the background image should not be repeated

**For example:** `repeat-x` will work for repeating a vertical background.

Comment: correction repeat-x is for horizontal repetition and repeat-y is for vertical repetition

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

Answer (score 0):

To repeat background vertically you can use `background-repeat: repeat-y;` But your CSS is not good to display that in fiddle.

I 'll suggest to use [box-shadow](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) for such things.